# Is it possible to redefine the default snippet for assigning a function to an event in C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

When assigning a function to an event and pressing tab Visual Studio helps by putting a default function name. For instance, when I type:

```
qp12.Form.OnGetHtml +=
```

and press tab Visual Studio completes this line as follows:

```
qp12.Form.OnGetHtml += new GenericForm.DelegateGetHtml(Form_OnGetHtml);
```

If I press tab once again VC will generate a method stub.

Is it possible to redefine the default function name generated by VC to a concatenation of object, property and event name? For instance:

```
qp12.Form.OnGetHtml += new GenericForm.DelegateGetHtml(qp12_Form_OnGetHtml);
```

I can refactor the name after creating the method stub but I am looking for a faster solution.

Comment: Then past that, you can refactor it to qp12.Form.OnGetHtml += qp12_Form_OnGetHtml;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not believe this is possible sorry.

That said if you are doing this a lot with one liner functions then you should consider writing it in lamdda style instead:

```
 qp12.Form.OnGetHtml += x =>  DoSomeThingWith(x);
```

If the functions are sizable then do it this way instead:

```
 qp12.Form.OnGetHtml += DoSomeThing;
```

Then you can use visual studio's [Generate Method Stub](http://blogs.msdn.com/ploeh/archive/2009/01/05/use-the-generate-method-stub-smart-tag-to-stay-in-the-zone.aspx) to actually create the method.

This is only one extra key press and results in (to me) much more readable code.